# jQuery each function not working for scroll top animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use the jQuery each function for scroll top animation in pagination each click but each function not working well it's working the first time only. Here are the code

```
$(".wp-pagenavi > a").each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var scroll = $("html, body");
        scroll.stop().animate({scrollTop:400}, 500, 'swing', function() { }); 
        console.log("click" + i);
    });
});
```

Please help me to reach out form this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `.each()`? It does not see to serve any meaningful purpose.

Comment: I want to scroll top for each pagination click using above code

Comment: Just remove `.each()` from your code and test again. If the issue still exists then we can try to figure out the cause.

Comment: Yes, I just removed and checked. It's still same

Comment: Now we know `.each()` was not the cause. Can you elaborate; what do you mean when you say _ it's working the first time only_? Is this something you can replicate here with a minimal snippet?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have only one element to click, where you want to scroll more the more often it is clicked?

Comment: @PeterKA check the below one

Comment: @Lalalena No actually I have more than one element like below pagination screenshot

Comment: I still don't understand your setup. The only time an event does not register is when the target element loads after DOM ready event in which case you'd have to use event delegation by changing `$(".wp-pagenavi > a").click(handler)` to `$(document).on('click', '.wp-pagenavi > a', handler)`.

Comment: Yes Now it's working thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible some of the target are loaded after DOM ready event in which case you would have to change your code to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wp-pagenavi > a', function() {
    var scroll = $("html, body");
    scroll.stop().animate({scrollTop:400}, 500, 'swing', function() { }); 
    console.log("click");
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please feel free to accept this as the **best answer**.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f46dnaue/3/

Is this the behaviour you are experiencing?
In the fiddle, `i` represents the index of the element being clicked. Clicking either element results in console output on every click.

Regarding your scrolling, should it always scroll to 400? If scroll is defined as 400, it is going to stay 400 no matter the number of clicks - so if you want your page to scroll by 400px steps you need to save the current scrollTop value and add an extra 400 to it for every click.